# Django does not load the maps in the admin panel

Tags: django, gis, admin, geodjango

I need to upgrade the Django version of a project that uses `GeoModelAdmin` for displaying maps in the admin panel. The recommended class to be used is `ModelAdmin` as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/admin/):

> Deprecated since version 4.0:
> This class is deprecated. Use ModelAdmin instead.

However, when I use `ModelAdmin` the maps do not load at all. And I get this error in the console:

```
GET https://gitc.earthdata.nasa.gov/wmts/epsg3857/best/BlueMarble_ShadedRelief_Bathymetry/default/%7BTime%7D/GoogleMapsCompatible_Level8/8/92/146.jpg 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Is there a configuration that I missed or there are problems with the server?

In the past I used `OSMGeoAdmin` which was exactly what I needed, but got it deprecated in Django 4.0. Now is suggested to use `GISModelAdmin` instead. When I use `GISModelAdmin` the maps are loaded, but I want to configure the zoom level and if I set the `gis_widget_kwargs` according to the documentation, nothing changes.

```
    gis_widget_kwargs = {
        "attrs": {
            "default_lon": 5,
            "default_lat": 47,
            "default_zoom": 3,
        }
    }
```

This happens with Django 4.2 and Python 3.12.

Later edit:

```
# models.py
class LandField(PostgresModel)
  shape = models.PolygonField(geography=True)
```

```
# admin.py
class LandFieldAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ...
```

Comment: The "500 Internal Server Error" means that there is a problem in the servers code. Since this is a NASA website, there's not much you can do about this. Most likely it means the URL you are using is incorrect. I can't give much more information than this for now without more code. Will you create a [mcve] that illustrates what you are trying to do?

Comment: I updated the question with some relevant code. In order to display geometries with the map widget in admin panel, in Django < 4.0 you usually inherited from `OSMGeoAdmin` or something similar. Now they suggest in the documentation to simply use `admin.ModelAdmin`. So I guess they moved the logic to `admin.ModelAdmin`. Might be a bug. I'll look into the source code.

Comment: It works now, there is no 500 Internal Server Error anymore. I guess it was a problem with the NASA servers cause Django fetches the maps images from there.

Comment: "Now they suggest ..." Who is "they"? Can you provide a link where you read this?

Comment: Also, thanks for adding some code. However, I can't run it myself because it is too incomplete. If you still need help, please add an example that I can actually run.

Comment: `They` means the Django maintainers, they can alter the code of `admin.ModelAdmin` from `Django`. As I said above, there was a temporary problem with the NASA servers, now everything works as expected, I will close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a temporary problem with the NASA servers that provided the map for the Django Admin widget. The widget works as expected now.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue half hour ago and I used:

[GISModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/admin/#gismodeladmin)

now It's working fine